# How do I get Resharper++ to ignore Qt moc files?

Tags: c++, qt, resharper

Resharper++ is parsing all the moc_ files generated by Qt. Has anyone figured out how to prevent this?

Comment: What's wrong with that? Those files are a part of your code, after all.

Comment: They're generated, not written.

Comment: I'm still curious why you need to explicitly exclude them from parsing. ReSharper C++ recognizes these files as auto-generated and should never try to change them.

Comment: It's giving me warnings in these files which I can't fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Third Party Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference_Options_Code_Editing_Third_Party_Code.html):

1. Go to ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | Third-Party Code.
2. In "File Masks" add "moc_*.cpp".